# Is the following code using options pattern?

Tags: c#

I'm reading this article on [Windows Services](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/09/27/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-2-the-topshelf-way/) and came across some code that I'm wondering about.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<LoggingService>();
            x.EnableServiceRecovery(r => r.RestartService(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
            x.SetServiceName("TestService");
            x.StartAutomatically();
         }
    );
}
```

Is this Options pattern code? What does this code look like in another more intuitive way?

Comment: Do you understand what the `x => ...` does?

Comment: lambda, or a delegate

Comment: nevermind i'll delete the question, sorry

Comment: don't have to do that -- trying to understand what you don't understand

Comment: This is hard to understand because there is alot of work being done by HostFactory -- but we are passing a function it is going to host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to write the same code....

```
public static void MyRun (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase service)
{
  service.Service<LoggingService>();
  service.EnableServiceRecovery(r => r.RestartService(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
  service.SetServiceName("TestService");
  service.StartAutomatically();
};


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HostFactory.Run(MyRun);
}
```

Is that clearer?